# WebSockets in Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

before I start this question I would like to say that I am new to WebSockets.

I have to create a client which contacts a server, and retrieves back the data that server sends. (With a username and password).

I've tried to use this: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

with no success (I'm not exactly sure which websocket jar I should use so I've just imported the jetty-all jar file). My program is literally exactly the same as the tutorial I've provided but once I've run it. It is littered with errors (the errors are to do with the imported jar file).

Now I've turned to Java EE WebSocket tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm

and I can't understand it for the life of me.

I'm not asking for complete code, maybe a guide on how to go about approaching this problem with Java EE. I'm struggling to find online resources that are purely Java based client sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the time (an hour) to investigate the technology further, here's a good tutorial about Sockets in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Here's some basic sample code for a server-side socket:

```
private final static int PORT_NUMBER = 3333;
    try (
        //ServerSocket listening to port 3333
        ServerSocket serverSocket =
            new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
        //ServerSocket.accept(); blocks program execution until a client socket connects,
        //put it in a loop to listen for continuous connections
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();    
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        //Read data from streams
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

On the client side you use a Socket to connect to your ServerSocket:

```
    Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
```

For example "hostname" could be "localhost" and "portnumber" in the sample above would be "3333". The hostname is the IP to which you are connecting.

Code samples are from Oracle.com, in the tutorial I linked.